# What do you call a number that represents 20 Percent written as "0.2" and "20%" respectively

Tags: notation, terminology

Lets say I want to represent 20 Percent

What do you call/name the "0.2" and "20%" notations

I am calling them Fractional and WholeValue notations for the time being, but wondering if there was something better.

Comment: I call them $1/5$

Comment: Decimal and percentage, perhaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would call "0.2" the decimal notation, and "20%" simply the percentage notation.

Comment: (1/2) I think there are two distinct meanings of "percentage" that are revealed by the "decimal notation" vs "proportion" answers to this question. Let's call them _notation_ and _description_.

Percent(age), decimal and fraction(al) are all forms of *notation*--ways to visually represent a number.

But a number can be a decimal and also a percentage: 0.2%, for example. So calling 0.2 a "decimal" doesn't tell us that it is _not_ a percentage, it just describes the notation. 0.2% is a decimal percentage, and 2/10% is a fractional percentage.

Comment: (2/2) In the case of 0.2% and 2/10%, the "%" _describes_ the preceding numbers--it tells us that we are talking, in both cases, about a _proportion_ of measured thing, and that the 0.2 or 2/10 are the numerator, and 100 is the denominator, of that proportion: 0.002.

Similarly, _describing_ a number 0.2 as a proportion tells us it is *not* a percentage. "The proportion M&Ms in the candy jar is 0.2." Means the same thing as "20% of the candy jar is M&Ms".  Compare to "The _decimal_ of M&Ms in the candy jar is 0.2."--not only is this sentence different in meaning, it is nonsensical.

Answer (score 4):

I would call "0.2" a proportion and "20%" a percentage.